# How to unit test a higher order component using jest and enzyme in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am currently trying to write a test to test what is inside of a higher order components

my test like so:

```
  let Component = withEverything(Header);
  let wrapper;
  it('renders correctly', async () => {
    wrapper = await mountWithSleep(
      <Component componentProps={{ session: { id: '2' } }} />,
      0.25
    );

    console.log(wrapper.debug());
  });
});
```

outputs the following:

```
<Component>
   <WithSession component={[Function: GlobalNav]} innerProps={{...}} />
</Component>
```

My with session file looks like the following:

```
import React, { Component, ComponentType } from 'react';
import { Session, session } from '@efa/web/src/modules/auth/authService';

import { Omit } from '@everlutionsk/helpers';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

class WithSession extends Component<Props, State> {
  state: State = {
    session: undefined
  };

  private subscription: Subscription;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.subscription = session.subscribe(session => {
      this.setState({ session });
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.session === undefined) return null;

    const Component = this.props.component;
    const props = { ...this.props.innerProps, session: this.state.session };
    return <Component {...props} />;
  }
}

/**
 * Injects a current session to the given [component].
 */
export function withSession<P extends SessionProps>(
  component: ComponentType<P>
): ComponentType<Omit<P, keyof SessionProps>> {
  return props => <WithSession component={component} innerProps={props} />;
}

export interface SessionProps {
  readonly session: Session | null;
}

interface Props {
  readonly component: ComponentType;
  readonly innerProps: any;
}

interface State {
  readonly session: Session | null | undefined;
}
```

I have tried to do a jest.mock which gets me part of the way using this:

```
jest.mock('@efa/web/src/modules/auth/components/withSession', () => {
  //@ts-ignore
  const original = jest.requireActual(
    '@efa/web/src/modules/auth/components/withSession'
  );
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...original,
    withSession: component => {
      return component;
    }
  };
});
```

Using this module i can at least see a returned component instead of with session. But now the issue is i need to be able to set the session state. wondering if anyone can help?!

It is worth noting this is a project which we inherited i would not of implemented it this way ever!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that this type of code absolutely makes testing more difficult. The "best" way in this case its probably a bit of work because the nicest way to go about it would be to switch this thing to context; and then add options to your test framework mount method to populate that context how you want from individual tests. Though, you can reach something similar with old fashioned HOCs.

There's a cheaper way, and that would be to allow options to be passed to `withEverything` (if this is used by the app as well, you can create a mirror one called `withTestHocs` or similiar. I.e.

```
withTestHocs(Header, {
    session: //... object here
})
```

Internally, this HOC would no longer call `withSession` whatsoever. Instead, it  would call a HOC who's only purpose is to inject that session config object into the component for test reasons.

There's no reason to do complex mocking to get the session right on every test, its a waste of time. *You only need that if you're actually testing `withSession` itself.* Here you should be prioritising your test framework API that makes having custom session per test nice and simple. `jest.mock` is not easily parametrised, so that in itself is also another good reason to not go down that road. Again, the exception is when you're unit testing the actual session hoc but those tests are typically quite edge-casey and wont be using the core "test framework HOC" you'll use for all your userland/feature code -- which is what I'm focusing on here.

Note with this solution, you wouldn't need the complex jest mocking anymore (provided all tests were moved to the new way).

```
export const withEverything =
  (Component, {session}) =>
  ({ providerProps, componentProps }) =>
    (
      <MockedProvider {...providerProps}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <FlashMessage>
            <Component {...componentProps} session={session} />
          </FlashMessage>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </MockedProvider>
    );
```

Now in your test

```
  it('renders correctly', async () => {
    wrapper = await mountWithSleep(
      const withEverything(Header, { session: { id: '2' }}),
      0.25
    );

    console.log(wrapper.debug());
  });
```

If you need to be able to manipulate the session mid-test, you could do that by returning a method from withEverthing that allows the session to be set, but im not sure if you need it.

Comment: Hi there! thank you for the response! So the with everything is 

```
export const withEverything = Component => ({ providerProps, componentProps }) => (
  <MockedProvider {...providerProps}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <FlashMessage>
        <Component {...componentProps} />
      </FlashMessage>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </MockedProvider>
);
```
This is used for purely testing purposes so i am still a little bit confused i think we will need to mock the with session

Comment: Ah if its already for testing, thats perfect. You can just remove the `withSession` then manually pipe the new session config object I suggested into the component you are testing. This config object *is* the mock, but you wont need to use jest mocking in any way (in my answer, im being literal about the meaning of mocking). Let me edit my answer with more detail shortly

Comment: OK Done. Essentially, my point is, you dont even need to run `withSession` in your test, you can just pass the session info and thats it. A good strategy would be to then test `withSession` later with its own unit test, but its overkill to basically implicitly test it with every single one of your other tests. I guess my answer is as much about testing strategy as it is the actual solution. I realise my solution is basically saying "why do this in the first place" -- and I think thats what you should consider.

Comment: If you need to change the session mid test, that can be built out further, let me know.